# Blender Internal texture not influencing geometry

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

When I try to add a new Clouds texture with geometry influence, I have nothing on the render.
I don't understand why?
I created a material : essai texture.
I created a new texture with clouds type:
Influence normal :0.552
size: 0.1
depth: 2.0
nabla: 0.10

Can you explain why?

Comment: can you share some detail of your object? it could have not enough geometry but also other properties (modifiers) that give you "nothing" in the render. btw, "nothing" means? no effect, or no object view at all?

Comment: hi, the object is a monkey with a subdivision surface and smooth.

Comment: i choice just a influence geometry nor at 1.000

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing a UV map. I did a simple "standard cube" setup to help you better debug what is missing or not working (here I used blender render for a quick setup):

[image]

After creating the texture as you said in question, I also got rendered a flat standard cube, but then I created a simple "smart UV project" umap, using all defaults, and just this made the influence to appear in rendering results.

A UV map is needed because your texture must be "mapped" to the mesh surface, and the UV map is how you tell about your desired surface mapping.

hth